# Are there any mantras that directly salute both Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, mantras

It is well known that “Om Namah Shivaya” is dedicated to Lord Shiva,and “Om Namo Narayana” to Lord Vishnu.

Is(are) there any mantra(s?) that is dedicated to both Lord Shiva and Vishnu at the same time?

Comment: The mantra of Harihara is the one you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

The Shiva Vishnu Bhujanga Prayata Stotram attributed to Sankaracharya:

https://www.hithokthi.com/viewstotra.php?g_id=1&cat_id=1&story_id=106

> Bhujanga prayata is a meter for writing poems in Sanskrit. It means moving of a snake. Adi Shankara has written several prayers using this meter. There is a very interesting story about this stotra. Adi Shankara reached his mother's death bed before she died. He wanted to help her get salvation. So he composed a great stotra called Shiva Bhujanga Prayata Stotra in praise of Lord Shiva. As soon as it was completed, The servants of Lord Shiva came to take Shankaras mother to heaven. But she was terrified to see them, because they wore the dresses of the forest and dressed in tiger skin with belts of snakes. Understanding her problem, Shankara humbly requested the servants of Lord Shiva to go back and composed this prayer to Lord Vishnu in the Bhujanga prayata meter. Once he recited it, the servants of Lord Vishnu, who had polished God like looks came to accompany Shankaras mother to heaven. She was extremely pleased to go with them.

> Anadyanthamadhyam, param thathwamartham,
> Chidakaramekam, thurreyam thwameyam,
> Haribrahma mrugyam, Parabrahma roopam,
> Mano vagatheetham maha shaivameede.

> Swashakthyadhi shakthyantha simhasanastham,
> Mano hari sarvanga rathnabhi bhoosham,
> Jataheendugangastha sasyarka moulim,
> Param shakthi mithram nama pancha vakthram.

> Namasthe,Namasthe Jagannata Vishno,
> Namasthe,Namasthe Gadha chakrapane,
> Namasthe,Namasthe prapannarthiharin,
> Samasthaparadham Kshamaswakhilesa.

> Mukhe mandahasam, nakhe chandrabhasam,
> Kare charu chakram, suresadhi vandhyam,
> BHujange sayanam, bhaje Padmanabham,
> Harenanya daivam na manye na manye.

translated from  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNrVfBaA4K8

> I meditate on that great light called Shaiva, Which has no beginning nor end, Which is the real meaning of philosophy, Which is the only one form of holy knowledge, Which is thureeya, the blissful fourth state, Which is the unknown which was, Searched by Lord Brahma and Vishnu, And which is the form of ultimate truth.

> I salute that God with five faces, Who sits on the throne of Adhishakthi, Using his own strength, Who wears mind stealing ornaments, Made of jewels all over his body, Who wears mated locks, snake, Moon and the river Ganga on his head, Who has moon and sun as his eyes, Who is the eternal god, And who has always with him Shakthi as consort.

> Salutations and salutations to Vishnu who is lord of universe Salutations and salutations to him who carries a mace and a wheel, Salutations and salutations to him who destroys sorrows of his devotees, And Oh Lord of everything, be pleased to pardon all my lapses.

> I salute the God with lotus flower on his belly Who has a smile in the face and the shine of moon in nails, Who holds pretty Chakra in the hand and Who is being saluted by devas and who sleeps on a serpent, And again and again affirm that there is no God except Hari.